# jquery fadein broken

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont knwo why the Jquery fade in is not working for my content div

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/blue.jpg" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div id="form">
            <form action="controler.php" method="post" id="target">
            <input id="pass" type="text" value="Password" name="pass" /></form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").fadeIn(2000);
    $('#pass').click(function() {
        this.value="";
        return false;
    });
});
```

It might be something small but I cant find it

Comment: what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `#content` is initially visible, then `fadeIn()` has nothing to do because the object is already visible.

If you set the initial style to `display: none`, then `fadeIn()` can do it's job.

To make it initially hidden, you can add this CSS:

```css
#content {display: none;}
```

Or, you can add an inline style tag:

```
<div id="content" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: or you can use  $("#content").hide().fadeIn(2000);

Comment: Why let it be initially visible before the JS runs, then hide it, then fade it in?  It's unlikely that's what the OP wants.  Much better to never be initially visible.

Answer (score 1):

Set the content div's initial state to display: none in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

a simple thing could be that the div isn't already hidden. So if already present, it won't fade in. When I've coded for these I have a generic class hidden to make it start invisible.
    
    ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide then fade in.

```
$("#content").hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as jfriend00 says it must be because your element with id content is not hidden since the beginning, copy-paste this code first and see if it works:

```
<div id="content" style="display:none">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/blue.jpg" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div id="form">
            <form action="controler.php" method="post" id="target">
            <input id="pass" type="text" value="Password" name="pass" /></form>
        </div>
</div>
```

if it works then simply remove the inline style "display:none" and add it to the styles of #content in your CSS file:

```
#content {
 display: none;
 /* the rest of your styles */
}
```

If this doesn't work there must be another problem, first thing to check id that you are including the JQuery library in the head of your document, make sure the path and syntax is well written, take this one for instance, I like to use google's API url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```